# meta tag w3c validation error html 5

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have this error while validating my web page(html 5) `"Bad value Cache-Control for attribute http-equiv on element meta."`.

This is my HTML code on page source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor site amet"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Lorem ipsum dolor site amet"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The `http-equiv` value `Cache-Control` is not allowed in HTML5.

You may only use the [values listed in the HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives) spec and those registered in the [WHATWG wiki page "PragmaExtensions"](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions).

If you need it and think it’s useful, you could try to [register it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#other-pragma-directives).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9657962/352260) is a very good answer for this question!