# Dublin Core and Metaname cause W3C Validation Issues in HTML5 page

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I use these tags in the head of an HTML5 page, but these cause problems in W3C Validation 
*Keyword is not registered*.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="Sitename - My Website" />
<meta name="keywords" content="graphic, security," />
<meta name="author" content="My Name" />
<meta name="identifier-url" content="" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="14 days" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
<meta name="Language" content="en" />
```

Same problem also with Dublin Core

```
<!-- Dublin Core -->
<meta name="DC.Title" content="My Site"/>
<meta name="DC.Subject" content="WebDesign; Analysis"/>
<meta name="DC.Description" content="This is my site bla bla bla"/>
<meta name="DC.Publisher" content="My Name"/>
<meta name="DC.Rights" content="Allrights reserved."/>
<!-- Fine Dublin Core -->
```

How I could fix this issue? If I delete these parts obviously the site run but I lost useful keywords that could help to better indexing my page.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665312/w3c-markup-validator-html5-meta

Comment: Also the suggestion is that do not use W3C validation if it doesn't work for your use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the standard `meta` names defined in the HTML5 spec:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names

Additional names [need to be registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names) at:
http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions

So [for HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669), you are free to use the `name` values listed on these two links, but values not listed there are not valid.

If you use a registered keyword and a validator reports it as error,  the validator is probably not up to date (new keywords can be registered in the wiki at any time).

---

EDIT: as requested in the comments, a valid example of the use with the name `dc.language`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="dc.language" content="en">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

You can validate it with http://validator.w3.org/ (using "Direct Input").

Comment: I have solved for the meta names, but there isn't a way to include dublin core without lost the W3C validation in HTML5?

Comment: @AndreaF: Dublin Core keywords are listed [in the wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions), too (like `dc.language`, `dcterms.alternative` etc.)

Comment: I have tried but for Dublin Core doesn't works any of these if I change meta name to dc.language etc., could you give me a working sample?

Comment: @AndreaF: I added a simple example to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your initial method was the right one. The HTML validator has been updated in the meantime and approves of it.

The `name` attribute in the HTML meta element has a few defined values - see the [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) -, but any other value is legal, too. So the following code will pass W3C's validator:

```
<meta name="dc.whatever" content="dunno">
```

To my knowledge, this is the only HTML5 compliant method to include DC metadata. Both the [Dublin Core documentation](http://dublincore.org/documents/dc-html/) and [WHATWG](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) (referenced by the W3C spec!) recommend the following before using `dc` values in `<meta>`:

```
<link rel="schema.dc" href="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
```

This is, however, not valid. There is a limited set of acceptable values for `<link rel="...">`, and `schema` is not among them: [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes)

For the same reason the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251383/2733244) produces invalid HTML - there is no link type `meta`. As far as I know, there is no way to include XML into HTML other than `<script>` (which looks more like a hack to me).

Probably switching to XHTML will be your best bet if you want to use Dublin Core.