# Which are the standard W3C meta tags?

Tags: html, meta-tags, w3c

What are the list of standard meta tags defined in W3C other than the below given at http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/meta

```html
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta name="copyright" content="© W3C" />
  <meta name="author" lang="en" content="" />
  <meta name="robots" content="Index,Follow" />
  <meta name="description"
        content="The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) is an international community
        where Member organizations, a full-time staff,
        and the public work together to develop Web standards." />
  <meta name="keyword" content="W3C, HTML, CSS, SVG, Web standards" />
```

Answer (score 13):

### HTML5

You can only use the following values in HTML5. If you need a value not listed, you’d have to register it first.

#### `name` values

- [Standard metadata names](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) (defined in the HTML5 spec)
- [MetaExtensions](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) (registered in the WHATWG wiki [according to the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names))

#### `http-equiv` values

- [Pragma directives](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives) (defined in the HTML5 spec)
- [PragmaExtensions](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions) (registered in the WHATWG wiki [according to the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#other-pragma-directives))

### HTML 4.01

In HTML 4.01 there is no registry defined, so you can use whatever values you like. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4:

> This specification does not define a set of legal meta data properties.

The spec gives some examples for `name` values, like:

- `author`
- `keywords`
- `description`
- `copyright`
- `date`
- `ROBOTS`

And for `http-equiv` values, like:

- `Expires`
- `PICS-Label`
- `Content-Type`