# XMLNS and semantical understanding by search engines

Tags: html, xml-namespaces, semantic-markup, dublin-core

I use a bunch of semantic markup on my site, from schema.org, Dublin Core, OGP, FBML, data-vocabulary. But since I use HTML5, the W3C-validator doesn't like all of `XMLNS` markups, like

```
xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/"
xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns/book#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"
```

**The question** is: if I don't use `XMLNS` (or `prefix:dcterms` etc), would search engines still understand the semantic of the site? Yes, Google Rich Snippets testing tool still shows all of markups … But the question still remains.

Such markup is used:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <meta property="og:title" content="Book-Title" />
      <meta name="dcterms.title" lang="de-DE" content="Book-Title"/>
   </head>
     <body>
      <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
        <h2 itemprop="name">Book-Title</h2>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which way (which syntax?) do you use it?

Comment: I use in meta tags dcterms:subject without the head declaration <html xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">. Other way i use it, is only Schema.org.markup in the body, like <span itemprop="name">. The question is the same: if using without the head namespace declaration, is the markup in the head (dc) and in the body (Schema) enough clear for search engines?

Comment: Could you please include examples of the markup in your `head` and `body` in your question?

Comment: added it below of the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using three different ways to specify metadata here:

#### `meta`-`name`

Your use of Dublin Core in `<meta name="dcterms.title" lang="de-DE" content="Book-Title"/>` is fine as it is, because you use a [registered HTML5 `name` value](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) here.

#### Microdata with schema.org vocabulary

Your use of Microdata with the schema.org vocabulary is fine as it is, because you specify the full URI:

```
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Book-Title</h2>
  </div>
```

#### RDFa with OGP vocabulary

With `<meta property="og:title" content="Book-Title" />` you are using the RDFa syntax (because of the `property` attribute), therefore you’d need to specify the URI, as `og` is a prefix here.

You could use a full URI instead of the prefix, e.g.:

```
<meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#title" content="Book-Title" />
```

You could specify the prefix in the `html` or `head` element with the `prefix` attribute:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Book-Title" />
</head>
```

Or you may use the `meta`-`name` instead of RDFa (in the same way you used the Dublin Core `dcterms.title`), because `og:title` is a registered HTML5 `name` value (depends on your use case if you may want to stop using RDFa here):

```
<meta name="og:title" content="Book-Title" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you please point out where did you get, that the og:title is a registered HTML5 name value?

Comment: It’s listed as "Registered Extension" in the [MetaExtensions](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions) page I linked. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669) for the links to the relevant section in the HTML5 spec.