# Error: Bad value twitter:domain for attribute name on element meta: Keyword twitter:domain is not registered

Tags: w3c-validation

How to enable tag name twitter:domain for twitter cards in w3c validator?

```
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="...." >
```

Comment: I think you want "property" instead of "name" here, see http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/bad-value-w-for-attribute-x-on-element-y-z/bad-value-twitterurl-for-attribute-name-on-element-meta-keyword-twitterurl-is-not-registered/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using HTML5, you may only use values listed [in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) and [in the WHATWG wiki page "MetaExtensions"](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669)).

As `twitter:domain` is [registered](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions) in the wiki, it’s valid to use it.

So the validator is not up to date.

Comment: yes but ... I always recibe  "Bad value twitter:domain for attribute name on element meta: Keyword twitter:domain is not registered."

Comment: @marcogomes: Yes, that’s what I explained: the validator is wrong.

Comment: I fix that change name=".." to property"..."  run ok in https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator

Comment: @marcogomes: By using `property` you are using [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa) now. That’s a possibility, of course, but as I explained, it would be totally fine to use the `twitter:domain` with plain HTML (by using `name`), too.