# Best metatag for copyright in html5

Tags: html, copyright-display, metatag

What is the best metatag to use in a html5 page to add the name of the Agency/CMS that developed the web application?

I have found these 3 options:

```
<meta name="author" content="My CMS name dot com" />

<meta name="application-name" content="My CMS name dot com" />

<meta name="dcterms.rights" content="My CMS name dot com" />
```

Not sure that the first 2 are still valid in html5

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, you [may only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669) use names that are [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) or [registered on WHATWG’s MetaExtensions wiki page](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions). So these are the two places where you can look for appropriate names.

[`author`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-author) is for the "name of one of the page's authors". As a (CMS) developer, you are probably not the author of the page, right?

[`application-name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-application-name) should not be used for the name of the CMS used to create the app, but for the name of the (created) app (only to be used if it’s an app, not for any kind of website).

[`dcterms.rights`](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions) doesn’t seem to be appropriate; it’s for (information about) the rights, and not *who* has the rights. And besides that, it’s for the created site/app/content, not the tools that made it possible.

You could

- use [`generator`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-generator) for specifying the CMS that was used for creating the site
- use [`web_author`/`designer`](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions) for [specifying the name of the developer/designer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/76895/17633)

Comment: I think the generator metatag is to specifiy the editor used to create the website (like: dreamweaver), but i'm not sure... instead "application-name" specifies the name of the Web application that the page represents (source w3c)

Comment: @ipel: It’s for "one of the software packages used to generate the document", and that would be clearly your CMS.

Answer (score 0):

@ipel,

I agree with [@unor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341539/11480716) of not using the 3 potential meta tags you've highlighted.

Have you considered adding a [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/Standard.html) file instead? Last option would be to add an HTML comment at the start of the HTML document.

```
<!-- Copyright © Year Publisher -->
```