# Meta tag migration from HTML 4.01 to HTML5

Tags: html, metadata, meta-tags, meta

We are looking at migrating over pages written in HTML 4.01 to HTML5 and am looking at the minimum requirements when including meta tags in the `<head>` element. For example, my current page which is HTML 4.01 compliant has the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta http-equiv="title" content="">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="created" content="2014-02-03T10:10:27.000-04:00">
<meta http-equiv="modified" content="2014-04-01T14:18:21.631-03:00">
<meta http-equiv="language" content="en">
<meta http-equiv="coverage" content="">
<meta http-equiv="publisher" content="">
```

My question is which one shoud be changed or removed and any other meta tag(s) need to be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no required `meta` elements (with one exception, see below).

You can’t use just any metadata name (`name`) or pragma directive (`http-equiv`) like it was case in HTML 4.01. [In HTML5, **all values must be defined/registered**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669) in a certain manner.

So you’d have to check the spec and the wiki for possible values. If a value is not listed, don’t use it (or, if you are sure about it, register it).

#### Exception: there is a `meta` element that is *sometimes* required

Only if you don’t specify the character encoding in a different manner (e.g. in the `Content-Type` HTTP header), you must use a `meta` element for specifying it. See [Specifying the document's character encoding](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#charset).

If you use UTF-8, just add the following `meta` element (ideally as the first child element of `head`):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```