# Minimum requirements for script tag & page validity

Tags: javascript, html, tags, w3c-validation

In some occasions, I have pages without any content but a script that does something (ex. sending data through [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) then closing itself).

In such cases, is the page valid with just `<script>doSomeStuff</script>` or does it also require a doctype like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>doSomeStuff</script>
</html>
```

Or does the page need full html declaration like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>doSomeStuff</script>
</head>
</html>
```

One might think it's wiser to include `<meta charset="UTF-8">` since otherwise the page could suffer from encoding errors and the script mis – or never – interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a valid HTML document, you have to follow the normal rules. There are no exceptions for documents that rely on JavaScript.

For your case, the minimal HTML5 document would be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Some title</title>
<script>doSomeStuff</script>
```

The [`title` element is sometimes optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943126/1591669), but likely not in your case.

The `meta`-`charset` element is only [required if you don’t specify the character encoding in a different manner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25585477/1591669).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it valid to open the html tag with the doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` without closing it at the end?

Comment: @Buzut: The DOCTYPE is not the opening tag for the `html` element. If you want to have the `html` start tag, your document would start with: `<!DOCTYPE html><html>` . For the `html` element, you can omit only the start tag (`<html>`) or only the end tag (`</html>`) or both tags (like in my minimal example) -- with [exceptions if comments are involved](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/semantics.html#the-html-element).