# Is it valid to use time stamp instead normal date format in meta tags?

Tags: html, metatag

Is it valid to use time stamp instead normal date format in meta tags?

for example:

```
<meta name="revised" content="Wednesday, September 24, 2014, 2:51 pm" />
```

to

```
<meta name="revised" content="1431475718" />
```

or for

```
<META NAME="Expires" CONTENT="1431475718">
```

Answer (score 3):

You [may not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669) use `revised` or `expires` in HTML5, as these metadata names are neither [defined in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) nor [registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names) on [MetaExtensions](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions).

No one tried to register `revised`. Someone tried to register `expires`, but a spec was missing, so it was not approved.

So …

- without specifications for these metadata names, authors don’t know when and how to use it, and consumers don’t know how to interpret it.
- if there are specifications, these metadata names could be registered on [MetaExtensions](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions), and it would be clear which format the value must have.

Answer (score 1):

From my research, [[1]](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) [[2]](http://dublincore.org/documents/2012/06/14/dcmi-terms/?v=terms#terms-date), it seems that there isn't a mandated format, however it is [recommended](http://dublincore.org/documents/2012/06/14/dcmi-terms/?v=terms#terms-date) to use ISO 8601.

> Date may be used to express temporal information at any level of granularity. Recommended best practice is to use an encoding scheme, such as the W3CDTF profile of ISO 8601 [W3CDTF].

Google also [recommends](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/70871?hl=en) following this format. You could use a timestamps and some crawlers will try to handle them (like Google), you would be better off following ISO 8601 (2015-05-03T15:38:45+00:00).