# How to solve this error : Bad value original-source for attribute rel

Tags: html, wordpress, w3c-validation

I am trying to validation my site with w3c but i am getting error:

```
 Bad value original-source for attribute rel on element link:
 The string   original-source is not a registered keyword.
```

For:

```
<link rel="original-source" href="http://themarketmogul.com/" />
```

Can any one suggest me what i can do for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rel` attribute specifies type of the link. There are limited set of values this attribute (the type) accepts. Specification defines them in section [4.8.4 Link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes):

- alternate - Gives alternate representations of the current document.
- author - Gives a link to the author of the current document or article.
- bookmark - Gives the permalink for the nearest ancestor section.

etc.

This list also includes probably the best known `stylesheet` type for importing CSS stylesheets. But there are 
no "original-source" type. Hence, the validation error you get.

In your case you probably looking for the `meta` tag with the name "original-source" (see codyogden's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the `meta` tag that [allows you to specify an original source](http://searchengineland.com/google-creates-metatags-to-help-id-original-news-sources-56115). A `link` is not the correct tag to use for this purpose.

```
<meta name=”original-source” content=”http://www.somedomain.com/article1.html”>
```

Comment: If the value is a URI, [`link` **must** be used instead of `meta`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669). Anyway, `original-source` isn’t registered as metadata name, so [it isn’t valid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669) to use it in HTML5 either.