# Added meta tags not picked up by metatagscheck.com

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

I have added `title` and `description` meta tags to the top of my `head` tag. After the page is loaded I can see the meta tags added in the source page.

However when I check it using http://www.metatagscheck.com/, the tags are not there.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var title=document.createElement('meta');
    title.name="title";
    title.content="Wholesale Prices of Manufacture, Distributors, Traders, Suppliers for GCC &amp; Africa";

    var description=document.createElement('meta');
    description.name="description";
    description.content="Find quality products over the world to get it at your place in GCC and Africa sourced through Manufacturers, Suppliers, Wholesalers, from the UAE, India, China, Turkey, Europe and US.";
    document.head.insertBefore(description, document.head.firstElementChild);
    document.head.insertBefore(title, document.head.firstElementChild);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool http://www.metatagscheck.com/ likely¹ doesn’t execute JavaScript on the page it tests. This is common for many tools (example: [W3C’s HTML5 validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)).

If you add the meta tags as HTML to the document (instead of adding them via JavaScript), the tool should be able to read them. Like it does read the `title`².

---

¹ We can only guess here, as its source code doesn’t seem to be published.

² The `title` element is different from the `meta`-`title` element. A [`meta`-`title` element is invalid in HTML5](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/71880/17633) (it [isn’t registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669), so it’s not allowed to use it).