# w3c markup validation

Tags: html, validation

```
Bad value copyright for attribute name on element meta: Keyword copyright is not registered.
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright (c) 2009-2013 Skyline" />
```

When I try to validate my code, i'm getting this error.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML specification defines a few names for the name attribute of the meta element.

`meta name="copyright"` is not defined in this specification.
Please try this:

```
<meta name="dcterms.rightsHolder" content="Copyright (c) 2009-2013 Skyline" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<meta name="dcterms.rightsHolder" content="Copyright (c) 2009-2013 Skyline">
```

See http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-rightsHolder for full details.

[See this post by Karl Horky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665312/w3c-markup-validator-html5-meta) for a full explanation