# Meta tag for theme author (copyright)

Tags: themes, meta, copyright-display

Im a theme author and I want to "brand" my theme, so that there is a meta tag, which says semething like "theme-author: Max mustermann".

Is there a meta tag like that (like copyright)?

Which one is the right?

Answer (score 0):

There was a meta tag used for copyright in the html4 standard, but it wasn't carried over to html5.

[Apparently there is:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9699659/1947286)

```
<meta name="dcterms.rightsHolder" content="Your Copyright-Holder Organization">
```

But in either case these meta tags probably shouldn't be used by the theme author, it looks like they are really intended for use by who ever owns the rights to the content.

**Usually this sort of thing is done with comment blocks not meta tags.**

Here's one from WordPress's 2014 theme:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fourteen
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: In 2014, our default theme lets you create a responsive magazine website with a sleek, modern design. Feature your favorite homepage content in either a grid or a slider. Use the three widget areas to customize your website, and change your content's layout with a full-width page template and a contributor page to show off your authors. Creating a magazine website with WordPress has never been easier.
Version: 1.2
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: black, green, white, light, dark, two-columns, three-columns, left-sidebar, right-sidebar, fixed-layout, responsive-layout, custom-background, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, flexible-header, full-width-template, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, translation-ready, accessibility-ready
Text Domain: twentyfourteen

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

[My personal favorite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769077/1947286), not exactly a copyright, but it is worth sharing:

```
/* The License:
You (from this point on referred to as The You) are hereby 
granted by me (from this point on referred to as The Me) 
license to knock yourself silly with this template. 
By using this template The You implicitly accepts this 
license and pledges solemnly to never claim creative 
ownership of any graphics, code, concepts, eggs, bacon, ideas, 
colors, shapes, hypertext-transfer protocols or other conduits 
of the visual splendor thatis this template. 

The Me, in turn, pledges equally solemnly to be far too 
lazy to ever check up on you, so if you do manage to pull 
some chicks The Me won't have a cow. 
However The Me would be sorely disappointed if The You 
were to try and sell or distribute this work without 
acknowledging The Me. Seriously. The Me will come down on 
The You like a large quantitiy of hard and heavy objects 
that in large quantities may be harmful and possibly even 
lethal to The You; So don't even think about it, The Buster.
*/
```